# How to test iOS 9 Search API indexing with Web Markup?

Tags: ios, ios9, corespotlight, applebot, ios-searchapi

I know, there is [App Search API Validation Tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool) which can tell you "Yeah, yeah, it's all good with your content and your users will be able to discover it if it will become popular and bla bla bla...", but is there any flag/setting/sandbox mode which will allow me to actually see my content in iOS Spotlight search results?

Comment: Do you have a sample for apple-app-site-association file? Because I got this message "The apple-app-site-association file was found but it doesn’t follow the required format." signed or not signed i have the same message.

Comment: See my answer to your question @Beto :)